# SELECT FOR UPDATE and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE causes deadlock in MYSQL on same row insertion

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, deadlock

I am performing multiple transaction concurrently and a case occurs when same row is checked through SELECT FOR UPDATE query and it is inserted or updated with INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. But this causes deadlock.

Here is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `a` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `b` date NOT NULL,
  `c` enum('a','b') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `d` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `e` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a, `b`, `c`, `d` )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Following are the transaction operations.

**In Transaction 1:**

```
Start Transaction;

SELECT  *
FROM t
WHERE
    a= '123'
        AND `b` = '2017-01-01'
        AND c= 'a'
        AND d= '1'
FOR UPDATE;

INSERT INTO t
(`a`, b, `c` , d, e)
VALUES ('123', '2017-01-01', 'a' , '1'  , '2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `e` = '2';

Commit;
```

**In Transaction 2:**

```
Start Transaction;

SELECT  *
FROM t
WHERE
    a= '123'
        AND `b` = '2017-01-01'
        AND c= 'a'
        AND d= '1'
FOR UPDATE;

INSERT INTO t
(`a`, b, `c` , d, e)
VALUES ('123', '2017-01-01', 'a' , '1'  , '2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `e` = '2';

Commit;
```

Deadlock occurs when both transaction have ran select for update and one of the transaction tries to insert the row.

**NOTE**: I need SELECT FOR UPDATE because I maintain a count on basis of previous result before result get updated. Deadlock is created due to insert.

**Question**: How I can avoid the issue of deadlock?

Comment: MySQL will not lock a specific row that does not yet exist (by coincidence, it's called "for update", not "for insert", although it is not actually the (whole) explanation.) You may be able to reorganize your queries, e.g. insert as the first step, or e.g. use a second table where you insert the row just to be able to lock it.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB's transaction handling is not perfectly precise.  For the sake of performance, some non-deadlocks are treated as deadlocks because the effort to discover otherwise is not worth the cost and rarity.

Live with it.  Restart the transaction that got zapped.